# Include all localized resources in MSI - VS2008

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, resources, windows-installer, satellite-assembly

I am building an MSI for a windows service application that has a set of satellite assemblies with localized resource data in them.

I can manually include the Localized content from the projects but since my application contains several projects with localized data, do i need to manually include them in the VS2008 msi file system view or can i somehow choose to include all satellites for the service and its dependencies?

Or is the solution to use WIX or some other installer instead of the default vs2008 msi.

Thanks in advance.